# Unable to retrieve the error associated and display in login page

Tags: angularjs, spring-security

Using AngularJS and Spring Security, when the authentication fails there is a redirect to the login page with `error=true`. I need to display this error on login page (AngularJS). I don't know how to do this.

Below is the declaration of `authentication-failure-url` in `ssecurity-context.xml`:

```xml
<security:form-login login-page="/login" 
                login-processing-url="/authenticate"  
                authentication-failure-url="/login?error=true"
                username-parameter="username" password-parameter="password"/>
```

Could some please tell me how to retrieve the error and show on login page?

**JS**

```
 angular.module('app.services')
.service('AuthenticateService'‌​,['$http','$location‌​',function($http,$lo‌​cation)
{ 
  return
       {    
        login : function(uname, pword)
                { 
                 var data = "username="+uname+"&password="+pword;
                 return $http.post("authenticate",data, 
                         {
                          headers: { "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" } })
                          .then(function (response) 
                          {
                            console.log(response.status);
                          },function(error)
                          { 
                            console.log(error.status);
                           });
                           }
                  }
}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

When your login attempt fails, you're redirecting to `/login/error/true`

Then, you should have on your angularJS a route to that URL with the partial HTML that you want to display, alongside with an angularJS controller which will handle or do the appropriate actions upon that URL.

For example, let's say that your route file will look this:

```
var myApp = angular.module("myApp", [ "ngRoute" ]);

myApp.config(function ($routeProvider) {

    $routeProvider
        .when("/login/error/:errValue", 
        {controller: "LoginController", templateUrl: "/partials/login.html"})
    });
```

**Now all you have to do is tho check on LoginController whether :errValue is true or false.** and act upon that value.

```
  with wrong credentials, I tried checking the value  of errValue in the controller, but its says undefined 

    Below are the routes declared

    $stateProvider
            .state("/login",{   //this for login page
            url:'/login',
            templateUrl:'./resources/js/baseapp/ContactLogin/views/contactLogin.html',
            controller:'contactLoginCtrl'
        })
        .state("/home",{
            url:'/home',      // this is for home page
            templateUrl:'./resources/js/baseapp/ContactHome/views/ContactHome.html',
            controller:'contactHomeCtrl'
        })
        .state("/login:error/:errValue",{   // this is for login error page
            url:'/home',
            templateUrl:'./resources/js/baseapp/ContactLogin/views/contactLogin.html',
            controller:'contactLoginCtrl'
        })
            $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/login");
```